# Stacked line area chart not working in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making an area line chart. It's not stacked because they don't sit on top of each of the other lines.

The line part and the area part aren't lining up. I'd like to show two groups in one area line chart.

This is my code

```
economics_long %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("unemploy", "pop")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value, group = variable,
             fill = variable, color = variable)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(size = 1)
```

The red line doesn't match up with the top of the red area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
economics_long %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("unemploy", "pop")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value, group = variable,
             fill = variable, color = variable)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.4,size=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code 2
economics_long %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("unemploy", "pop")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value, group = variable,
             fill = variable, color = variable)) +
  geom_line(size=1)+
  geom_area(alpha = 0.4,size=1,position='identity')
```

Output:

[image]

Or this stack style:

```
#Code 3
economics_long %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("unemploy", "pop")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value, group = variable,
             fill = variable, color = variable)) +
  geom_line(size=1,position='stack')+
  geom_area(alpha = 0.4,size=1,position='stack')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It's code 2 that works for me, can you please add an explanation for why it's not working?

Comment: @Cauder Yes, sure. The reason are the different positions, it looks like when you set the default line and area, the positions are different (in one case for line identity and for area a stacked style). Setting position identity in area makes that both line and area have the same style. That is why it works. Let me know if that was clear enough for you!